# Server document root and folder in different machines

Tags: php

I am using tDPDF to use unicode font. The problem is that i am creating my web page using xampp, testing on Raspberry Pi LAMP server and uploading on my server. All of them have different server document root address which it is causing an error on a unicode file(php). It has the following line

Xampp File

```
$ttffile='C:\xampp\htdocs\app-final\fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf';
```

I must change it to something that it will work to all my address, like

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\app-final\
192.168.1.10/html/
172.20.10.1/www/
```

I tested the following but missing the folder in each machine(app-final, html, www, etc...)

```
$ttffile=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf";
```

My links so far:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\app-final\fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf
192.168.1.10/   html/     fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf
172.20.10.1/    www/      fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf
```

Comment: Did you try `$ttffile=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/app-final/fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf";` I am assuming that your DocumentRoot folder is `C:\xampp\htdocs` and on ALL 3 systems the folder `app-final\fpdf/font/unifont/Calibri.ttf` exists below the DocumentRoot

Comment: @RiggsFolly Each system have different folder. Must found a solution to get this folder as it is the main folder of the web site.

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1)../app-final/.. 2)../html/.. 3)../www/.. 4)something else and so go on...

Comment: My point is if you directory structure BELOW the DocumentRoot is the same on all system my first comment should work. If however the directory structure is different on any of the 3 systems YOU GOT PROBLEMS

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, i know. Only the folder that the all pages is different. I must update everytime the file in order to make it work.

Comment: So fix the folder structure on all your test system to match your LIVE system. That is a pre-requisite of a development system, it has to match the LIVE environment

Comment: Also as 2 of your systems appear to be LINUX the concept of `C:\\` anything does not compute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so simple

```
$ttffile= __DIR__ . "/Calibri.ttf";
```